# How to uninstall definitely IE8 from Windows Server 2008 R2?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, internet-explorer-8

I have a Windows Server 2008 R2, Enterprise Edition SP1. I need to uninstall IE explorer 8 from this server but can't find IE in installed updates or uninstall programs from the control panel?

I don't know how to uninstall this EOL version from my server for security audit requirements.

Comment: Once you get rid of IE 8, how is Server 2008 going to pass any security audit? It's been end of even the most optimistic extended support period for over two years.

Comment: For this server, an ESU license for three years is applied

Comment: Try Control Panel, Programs and Features, Windows Features. It should be there. I see it on my Windows 10 machine.

Comment: I can't see IE in Control Panel, Programs, and Features, Windows Features for the Windows Server 2008 R2?

Comment: It goes all the back to XP and before.  It could never be fully uninstalled,  It may not have been enabled, but nonetheless it is built into the OS and the bits the OS needs will always remain.

Comment: Why do you need to uninstall it?

Answer (score 1):

Internet Explorer is a feature that can be disabled.
The Windows Features dialog box (optionalfeatures.exe) is however only available on client versions of Windows.
On Windows Server you can install or uninstall features by using the Server Manager (but Internet Explorer is not listed there), DISM or Powershell (at least in later versions of Windows Server).

Your best bet would be to use DISM on Server 2008 R2.
Execute the following command in CMD, this should disable Internet Explorer.

```
dism /online /disable-feature /featurename:Internet-Explorer-Optional-amd64
```

Answer (score 0):

For Windows Personal computer and Windows Servers, Internet Explorer shows up in Control Panel, Programs and Features, Windows Features.   Open Windows Features.

It is there in Personal Computers with Windows 10 and back to at least XP if not before.

IE could be enabled on Server 2012 and servers prior so certainly Server 2008.

In a standard Native setup (not hacked in some way), Internet Explorer could not be completely and totally uninstalled.

It could be disabled in Windows Features but basic elements of IE would remain as these were built into the operating system.

In your case IE may have already been disable in Windows Features.  if it cannot be enabled (nothing there to enable), then your system may have been hacked a registry change or there may be some other issue.

So then, since Server 2008 is so long out of support, there is (a) nothing you can do or (b) contact Microsoft Support (you say an extra 3 years of support was added) but remember Microsoft will more than likely charge you for the service.

If your Server is otherwise operating properly, there is no "need" to uninstall IE - it does not cause issues in a Native, properly operating server.